# How to return datetime in user define function

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have here a user define function that returns a datetime. I have set the month, day, and year for the next date basing on the original date.
I would like to know if how am I going to make the function return a date time format, a format like this : mm/dd/yyyy.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_get_payout_date]
(
   -- Add the parameters for the function here
   @m_id as int
)
RETURNS Datetime
AS
BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
--the original date
DECLARE @m_createddate as Datetime 
--the date to be returned
DECLARE @p_date as Datetime
--the day part of the original date
DECLARE @dpart as int
--the month part of the original date
DECLARE @mdate as int
--this determines the day part of the given day ranges
DECLARE @pday as int
--the year part of the original date
DECLARE @ydate as int


--get the original date
SET @m_createddate = (SELECT [m_createddate] FROM rms_month_email where m_id = m_id)
SET @dpart = DATEPART(dd,@m_createddate)
SET @mdate = DATEPART(mm,@m_createddate)
SET @ydate = DATEPART(yyyy,@m_createddate)

--if the dpart ranges between 1 -> 15, the day of pay out will be on the 15th
if @dpart >= 1 and @dpart <= 15 
        set @pday = 15

 else 
-- if the dpart ranges between 15-> 16, the day of pay out will be on the 30th
        set @pday = 30
--add 1 to month part of the original date to signify that it will be on the next month
SET @mdate = @mdate + 1


if @mdate > 12 
    SET @mdate = 1 
    SET @ydate = @ydate + 1

    SET @p_date = @mdate+'/'+@pday + '/'+@ydate
-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @p_date

END
```

but I got null in the value field.
Can you please advise what's wrong in my code?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `... where m_id = @m_id`?

Comment: Please tag dbms product used, since this is product specific and not ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the variables are getting null by printing them individually, because while you are concatanate the variable if any one is null then complete string will become null.

Answer (score 1):

`select convert(varchar(10), cast('2015-10-12' as date), 101)`
`select convert(varchar(10), cast(<column> as date), 101) from <table>`